# Se reinicia la pagina luego de subir el segundo archivo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

He creado una subida de archivos funciona bien cuando es la primera vez que subo un archivo, cuando lo vuelvo a intentar, si se sube el archivo, lo que no debería hacer es recargar la pagina ya que utilizo Ajax para enviar esto, soy nuevo en el tema ya he buscado bastante y no le encuentro solución.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".messages").hide();    
var fileExtension = "";  
$(':file').change(function ()
{        
    var file = $("#imagen")[0].files[0];        
    var fileName = file.name;        
    fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);        
    var fileSize = file.size;        
    var fileType = file.type;       
    showMessage("<span class='info'>Archivo para subir: " + fileName + ", peso total: " + fileSize + " bytes.</span>");
});

$(':button').click(function () {        
    var formData = new FormData($(".formulario")[0]);
    var message = "";        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            message = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo la imagen, por favor espere...</span>");
            showMessage(message)
        },            
        success: function (data) {
            message = $("<span class='success'>La imagen ha subido correctamente.</span>");
            showMessage(message);
            if (isImage(fileExtension))
            {
                $(".showImage").html("<img class='img-thumbnail img-fluid' style='height: 400px;width: 400px;'src='files/" + data + "' />");
                $(".hiden_name").html("<p>"+ data +"'<p/>");                                          
            }
        },

        error: function () {
            message = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    });
});
```

})

function showMessage(message) {
    $(".messages").html("").show();
    $(".messages").html(message);
}

function isImage(extension)
{
    switch (extension.toLowerCase())
    {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'gif':
        case 'png':
        case 'jpeg':
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}

#### front-end

```
  <div class="container">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario">
            <label>Subir un archivo</label><br />
            <input name="archivo" type="file" id="imagen" ><br /><br />                
        </form>
        <button id="enviarDatos" class="btn btn-success">Enviar datos</button> <br /><br />              
        <!--div para visualizar mensajes-->
        <div class="messages"></div><br /><br />
        <!--div para visualizar en el caso de imagen-->
        <div class="showImage "  ></div>
        <div class="hiden_name">            
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### archivo.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
{


$file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];


if(!is_dir("files/")) 
    mkdir("files/", 0777);


if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"files/".$file))
{

}
}else{
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que tienes un button dentro del form y te lo toma como un submit, por eso se recarga la página, al no tener un action definido en el form.

**SOLUCION:**

> Prueba a sacar ese boton fuera del form y llamarle como lo vienes haciendo.

```
<button id="enviarDatos" class="laclasequeledescss">Enviar datos</button>
```

Y llamarle de esta manera:

```
$('#enviarDatos').click(function () {
```

Pruebalo y me cuentas

Comment: mira mi archivo de JS que tenia hice los que me comentaron pero sigue dando problemas crei q estaba seguro q era el Ajax pero les paso el JS completo para descartar otra cosa que no este viendo '  '

Comment: cambie el JS para que puedan evaluarlo mejor gracias a todos por sus aportes :)

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres que haga submit cambia el valor de retorno de la función, en el evento success.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',        
    data: formData,     
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
        message = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo la imagen, por favor espere...</span>");
        showMessage(message)
    },

    success: function (data) {
        message = $("<span class='success'>La imagen ha subido correctamente.</span>");
        showMessage(message);
        if (isImage(fileExtension))
        {
            $(".showImage").html("<img class='img-thumbnail img-fluid' style='height: 400px;width: 400px;'src='files/" + data + "' />");
            $(".hiden_name").html("<p>"+ data +"'</p>");
             //return true; // El input lo tienes dentro de un form, evita el submit
             return false;
        }
    },      
    error: function () {
        message = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
        showMessage(message);
    }
});
```

Comment: en el evento success ;)